# Extract string matching regex from string

Tags: regex, xquery

I'm trying to extract a date from a string using XQuery.

```
let $string := "This string has a yymmdd date like 151123 in it."
(: I need the date bit -> 151123 :)
let $regex := "[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
```

Using `replace()` and `tokenize()` I can get everything other than the matched string. The `functx:get-matches()` function looks like it might do the trick but I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the whole string, group the date and replace with the group :

```
fn:replace($string, "^.*([0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]).*$", "$1")
```

I'm not able to test the code but hopefully you'll get the general process.

Answer (score 5):

XQuery 3.0 has the wonderful `analyze-string()` function:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $string := "This string has a yymmdd date like 151123 in it."
(: I need the date bit -> 151123 :)
let $regex := "[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
return 
    analyze-string($string, $regex)
```

Returns:

```
<fn:analyze-string-result xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <fn:non-match>This string has a yymmdd date like </fn:non-match>
    <fn:match>151123</fn:match>
    <fn:non-match> in it.</fn:non-match>
</fn:analyze-string-result>
```

Thus to get your matching string, you can simply request `analyze-string($string, $regex)//fn:match`.

Comment: analyze-string($string, $regex)//fn:match/text()